# Identifying unquoted special characters in shell command text

Tags: c, shell, posix, special-characters

I am implementing the [`wordexp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html) function, which needs to identify and optionally reject occurrences of command substitution (i.e. `$(...)` or backticks), and which, from a quality standpoint, should also identify and reject unquoted occurrences of the special characters `|`, `&`, `;`, `<`, and `>` whenever command substitution is disabled.

What I'm looking for is a simple way to identify the presence of these special characters without duplicating a huge amount of shell logic. Any ideas?

Once the string is validated, I'm passing it to `sh` with the following `-c` argument:

```
printf '%s\0' [string inserted here]
```

which builds a nice multi-string ready for consumption by the C code.

Comment: The whole point of wordexp is to centralize the duplication of the shell logic which is needed to perform its function.  The numerous security breakage due to people searching simple ad hock solution is there to show that recognizing that a special character is in position to be interpreted as special is not easy.

Comment: I didn't ask for an approximate solution, just a simple one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach seems to be correct, but I'd welcome corrections if it's wrong:

If the `WRDE_NOCMD` flag is not specified, don't do any checking. The specification for `wordexp` says the application

> shall ensure that words does not contain an unquoted  character or any of the unquoted shell special characters ...

and there is certainly no security benefit gained from checking for bogus special characters outside of command-substitution contexts when command-substitution is already allowed.

Now, if `WRDE_NOCMD` is specified, process the string sequentially, keeping a flag for whether we're in a single-quoted or double-quoted context.

- Encountering a backslash in a non-single-quoted context skips the next character.
- Encountering a single quote in a non-double-quoted context toggles the single quote context.
- Encountering a double quote in a non-single-quoted context toggles the double quote context.
- Encountering a backtick, or a `$(` not immediately followed by another `(`, in a non-single-quoted context results in `WRDE_CMDSUB`.
- Encountering any of the special characters in a non-quoted context results in `WRDE_BADCHAR`.

Since we're going to disallow all command substitution, there are no nested `$(` contexts to worry about; entering the first level already generates an error.

Have I made any stupid (or subtle and not-so-stupid) mistakes here?

Comment: One problem: it disallows `$((...))` arithmetic. :-( Fixing this doesn't seem too hard but requires keeping a count of parenthesis levels and treating the region inside similar to a double-quoted context.